# dealing with complex results in objects -- exceptions?

Tags: php, oop, exception

What is the general way of handling complex results from functions with an object? A simple method might return true or false, and that would be all I need to know. A more complex method might return true or false, but there might be more information I would want to get out of the class, such as why it failed ( there might be several reasons ).

I could do it with an exception, but I've read in some places that using an exception for a "normal" functions isn't good practice. Also since throwing an exception destroys the object, I can't do anything else with it, so an exception wouldn't work if I want to continue to use the object. It seems to me that an exception should be thrown when things are really wrong, not an expected, recoverable error.

So, another way to this is to have a result property after having run a method, and if that method returns false, I can ask what the result state for it is. Is this the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious solution: Return an array, like `("success" => false, "explanation" => "saw a mouse and ran screaming like a little girl", "solution" => "call an exterminator")`.

Comment: Yeah -- one downside is that array keys are amenable to typos ( "Why the H*!$ can't I get an explanation from this flippin' method!?" ) whereas if I mistype a method, I know right away, because I get an error.

Comment: Plus, who desides the key for "success"? Can't it be "status", "failure", "accepted" ...?

Comment: @chlemertz - You could make it part of your API

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions do not destroy the object, but if you catch an exception in a place where you have no reference to the object, then you can loose the object - it is still there until garbage collection.

If you create your own exception class you could even add the object in question as a member to the exception, so the object is available where you handle the exception.

The exception to this rule is when you throw an exception in an object constructor. Then the object in question is *never created in the first place*.

The use of Exceptions vs other error mechanisms is as old as Exceptions are. Exceptions are *a* method for handling errors and in many circumstances they work very well and result in cleaner code than when not using them.

Whether they are a good solution for a specific problem is partly a matter of experience, so you will have to try them out to learn to use them.

Comment: Are you sure exceptions don't destroy the object? I tried this code:
<?

class exceptor {

        public function __construct() {
                throw new Exception("I except!");
        }

        public function test() {
                return "test";
        }
}

try {
        $objExceptor = & new exceptor();
} catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "<BR>\n";
}

echo $objExceptor->test() . "<BR>\n";

And got this result: 

Caught exception: I except!<BR>

Fatal error: Call to a member function test() on a non-object on line 20

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying: they don't remove the object from memory. How can I access an object after it throws an exception?

Comment: Don't throw the exception in the constructor and you should be fine.

Comment: I added an explanation how you can keep a reference to your object after the exception is thrown and what happens when you throw an exception in a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to always keep the methods signatures' predictable, i.e. always return the same type (be it an array, boolean, anything else.)

I think [the example of validating with `Zend_Validate`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html#zend.validate.introduction.using) uses a sensible solution to your problem by **differentiating the result from the eventual errors.**